# Change colours of ComboBox Autocomplete dropdown list

Tags: .net, combobox, autocomplete, rendering

I've made a custom ComboBox User Control. Main aim is rendering it in dark mode. I've managed to achieve most of this. However, I'm stuck at how to modify the autocomplete drop-down (that is apply back and fore colors).

Here's the problem:

[image]

I'm modifying the combobox rendering via this code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)

    Select Case m.Msg
        Case &HF
            Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

            ' Full Control Background
            g.FillRectangle(_BorderBrush, Me.ClientRectangle)
            If Me.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown Then
                g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor), _BorderWidth, _BorderWidth,
                            Me.Width - _ButtonWidth - (3 * _BorderWidth),
                            Me.ClientRectangle.Height - (2 * _BorderWidth))
                ' DropDown Button Background
                Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Me.Width - _ButtonWidth - _BorderWidth, _BorderWidth,
                                                  _ButtonWidth, Me.Height - (2 * _BorderWidth))
                g.FillRectangle(_DropButtonBrush, rect)

            ElseIf Me.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList Then
                g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor), _BorderWidth, _BorderWidth,
                            Me.Width - (2 * _BorderWidth),
                            Me.ClientRectangle.Height - (2 * _BorderWidth))
            End If

            ' Drop Down BUtton Arrow
            Dim pth As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
            Dim TopLeft As PointF = New PointF(Me.Width - _ButtonWidth - _BorderWidth + 2, (Me.Height - 5) / 2)
            Dim TopRight As PointF = New PointF(Me.Width - 6, (Me.Height - 5) / 2)
            Dim Bottom As PointF = New PointF(Me.Width - 9, (Me.Height + 2) / 2)
            pth.AddLine(TopLeft, TopRight)
            pth.AddLine(TopRight, Bottom)
            g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

            g.FillPath(_ArrowBrush, pth)

        Case Else
            Exit Select
    End Select

End Sub
```

I don't fully understand the WndProc process, but I'm wondering if there's another code for the autocomplete dropdown rendering? However, not sure how to go about finding these codes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting issue. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e17a1359-348d-445a-9830-ca8cde24d2a8/how-to-change-background-color-in-autocomplete-window-?forum=visualfoxprogeneral) explanation and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu) solution in this regard.